# Why does my sprite not constantly appear instead of animating through images when stood still

Tags: python, animation, pygame

So as I'm creating a game, my sprite is a bat. So far when the user holds down the left or right key, the animation works perfectly fine; however, I've tried to add in where the user is standing still, the 'flying' animation still plays, facing the direction the player was last facing so it doesn't look like the bat is simply just floating still.

The outcome I get is the sprite doesn't appear on the screen unless I hold one of the movement keys down, when I just want it to be animating constantly, even when the user isn't moving.

I can get the sprite to face a certain direction by displaying a single image when stood still, but not properly animate.

I have heard of the library pyganim, but I can't use it due to the environment I'm in, so I'm struggling with options.

Here's the relevant code for the draw function:

```
     def draw(self,window): 
#we must keep track of direction, are they moving and how many steps for frames
        if self.walkcount +1 >= 15: #15 as we have 5 sprites, which will be displayed 3 times per second
            self.walkcount = 0

        if not(self.standing): #if hes not standing still or moving, we'll walk through our animation 
            if self.left:
                window.blit(walkleft[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y))#excludes remainders
                self.walkcount+=1
            elif self.right:
                window.blit(walkright[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y)) 
                self.walkcount+=1
            elif self.isjump:
                window.blit(jumpp,(self.x,self.y))
                self.walkcount+=1
        else: #if he is, we'll blit him looking right or left
            if self.right:
                if self.walkcount +1 >= 15:#
                    self.walkcount = 0#
                    while True:#
                        #anim1.blit(window,(self.x,self.y)) #previous attempt
                        #window.blit(walkright[0],(self.x,self.y)) #displays first image of that direction when stood still
                        window.blit(walkright[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y))
                        self.walkcount+=1
            else:
                if self.walkcount +1 >= 15: 
                    self.walkcount = 0#
                    while True:#
                        #anim2.blit(window,(self.x,self.y))
                        #window.blit(walkleft[0],(self.x,self.y))
                        window.blit(walkright[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y)) 
                        self.walkcount+=1
```

This is where the basic animations are done for where right or left is true, the animation will play while it is true.

The actual bit I've been editing in attempt to get it to work:

```
else: #if he is, we'll blit him looking right or left
            if self.right:
                if self.walkcount +1 >= 15:#
                    self.walkcount = 0#
                    while True:#
                        #anim1.blit(window,(self.x,self.y)) #previous attempt
                        #window.blit(walkright[0],(self.x,self.y)) #displays first image of that direction
                        window.blit(walkright[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y))
                        self.walkcount+=1
            else:
                if self.walkcount +1 >= 15: 
                    self.walkcount = 0#
                    while True:#
                        #anim2.blit(window,(self.x,self.y))
                        #window.blit(walkleft[0],(self.x,self.y))
                        window.blit(walkright[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y)) 
                        self.walkcount+=1
```

The movement functions:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel-man.vel: #if pressed we move our character by the velocity in whatever direction via grid which works from the TOP LEFT of screen
                                                    #vel-vel to equal 0, makes border better
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True #were global variables
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width: 
        man.x += man.vel                #screenwidth
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.standing = True #now we'll know if he's looking left or right
        man.walkcount = 0
```

Any other suggestions/feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when standing still, you set:

```
    man.standing = True #now we'll know if he's looking left or right
    man.walkcount = 0
```

so `walkcount` is `0` and `standing` is `True`.

In the `draw` function, `not(self.standing)` is `False`, so we jump to the `else` block.

There's another `if/else`, and on each branch you check

```
if self.walkcount +1 >= 15:
```

which will never be `True` because `walkcount` is `0` so the `window.blit` lines in either branch will never be reached; hence the image is not blitted to the window.

---

Without testing it, I think the entire method could be simplified to

```
 def draw(self,window): 

    #we must keep track of direction, are they moving and how many steps for frames
    if self.walkcount +1 >= 15: #15 as we have 5 sprites, which will be displayed 3 times per second
        self.walkcount = 0

    if self.isjump:
        window.blit(jumpp,(self.x,self.y))
    else:
        if self.left:
            window.blit(walkleft[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y))#excludes remainders
        else:
            window.blit(walkright[self.walkcount//3],(self.x,self.y)) 

    self.walkcount+=1
```

and the line

```
    man.walkcount = 0
```

should be removed.

Comment: Apologies firstly for the late reply, but your solution works perfect. I now see where I've gone wrong - thank you for the quick & efficient response.